# Derivatives using chain rule. $f(x) = (7x^3 + 2)^3(6x^2 - 1)^4$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I understand how to use the chain rule with simple functions. But in this there are two core's too choose from. Can't wrap my head around how to even start. Please help, been stuck on this for too long...

$$f(x) = (7x^3 + 2)^3(6x^2 - 1)^4$$

Comment: You have to use product rule and then apply chain rule to each part.

Comment: Do i  include the exponentiations when i use the product rule? or only the core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$g(x) =(7x^3 + 2)^3, \quad h(x) = (6x^2 - 1)^4$$

Then by the product rule: $$f'(x) = g'(x) h(x) + g(x) h'(x)$$

Now simply find $g'(x), h'(x)$ (use chain rule with each), and you have all the pieces you need to find $f'(x)$.

All that is left after substitution is simplification.

Comment: Thank you! Both answers together made very good sense

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

we have by the product, chaine and power rule
$f'(x)=3(7x^3+2)^221x^2(6x^2-1)^4+(7x^3+2)^34(6x^2-1)^312x$
the simplified result in a few minutes
we get by simplifying
$f'(x)=3\, \left( 7\,{x}^{3}+2 \right) ^{2} \left( 6\,{x}^{2}-1 \right) ^{3}x
 \left( 238\,{x}^{3}-21\,x+32 \right) 
$